# Spinner Usage in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to use spinner in my project. I have some activities like cycling, jogging, sleeping etc.

## SPINNER.XML

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/activitySpinner"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:entries="@array/activities"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="110dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="101dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

## ACTIVITIES

```
<string-array name="activities">
        <item>Jogging</item>
        <item>Cyclingn</item>
        <item>Football</item>
        <item>Course</item>
        <item>Cinema</item>
        <item>Music</item>
        <item>Eat</item>
        <item>Sleep</item>
</string-array>
```

## CODE

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        //-----------ACTIVITY SPINNER---------------
        case R.id.activitySpinner:
            activitySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
            break;
        //-----------ACTIVITY SPINNER---------------

    }
}
```

I just want to select items when the activity loaded. I've tried to do

```
activitySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

Inside the onCreate() but it crashes as same as the example that above.

I guess using onClick() with setOnItemSelectedListener() is wrong but i dont know how can i handle this. Thanks

**I'm working on SDK25 and above(6.0)**

**ERROR**
[Pastebin error](https://pastebin.com/ZFqrrFhz)

Comment: Inside the onClick wont work, because you are setting the onItemSelectedListener after a click, so the method will only be called after an onClick happen. What is the error you are getting when putting the setOnItemSelectedListener inside the onCreate? This is the correct way to do things.

Comment: I forgot writing error. Check here in 2 mins

Comment: "setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener"

Are you trying something like this: activitySpinner.setOnClickListener( OnItemClickListener )?

You should do: activitySpinner.setOnItemClickListener ( OnItemClickListener )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you're using

```
setOnItemSelectedListener
```

inside a OnClickListener

you need to just use `activityspinner.getSelectedItem();`